# How to perform action after a queue of function calls is consumed in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In Azure, I have created a queue of items, which are consumed by an Azure function. I would like to group these items in the queue, so that after a batch of items are consumed, then I will do another action, e.g. send an email. I am new to Azure, and wanted to know is there to batch/manage a group of function calls to do an action after the batch is processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible to do so. Do look into [`Azure Durable Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp).

Based on the description, you can implement [`Function Chaining`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#chaining) pattern where output of one Function can be fed to another Function. In this case the items will be processed sequentially.

[image]

You can also implement [`Fan out/fan in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#fan-in-out) pattern if you want the items in your queue to be processed in parallel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. With Function chaining, will the durable function timeout, if the sum of the chained function time exceeds x minutes (e.g. 30 minutes)?

Comment: I don't think the total execution time of all functions would matter. However each Function in the chain cannot exceed 10 minutes I believe.